# Does a ghouled creature's natural attack cause aggravated damage?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

A pack of newly-ghouled wolves (ghouled by a Gangrel NPC) may enter combat in our next game session and I am trying to figure out whether their bite attack will cause the same type of damage as they would if the creature were not a ghoul (lethal) or, as the claws or teeth of a supernatural creature (aggravated damage).

I know it's impossible to prove a negative, but are Ghouls not classified as supernatural creatures? If not, a ghouled wolf with a bite attack that normally deals Str + 1 dice of Lethal damage (plus Potence) would need to use Protean ●● Feral Claws to grow claws that would then deal Str + 1 dice of Aggravated damage (plus Potence).

Answer (score 3):

Lethal only, as far as I know they get one dot of potence and this is the only thing that will affect damage compared to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Ghouling does not automatically extend the ability to spend Vitae to deal DMG(A). Animals do not, in general, gain any abilities other than what an animal Ghoul usually receives. They cannot deal DMG(A) unless empowered via other supernatural means to do so. So in your situation they will deal DMG(L).

UPDATE

You've answered your own question with a variant on my answer, hah hah. Again, "**unless empowered via other supernatural means to do so**" (e.g. Protean, Vicissitude), they do damage as normal.